# Validation message wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am developing an MVC 5 Application.  I have Validation messages for fields that are Required and that should be a number, etc.  Picture of how the validation is currently displaying shown below (note these are same field in both images):

[image: Required Field Validation]
[image]

I am using bootstrap and the cshtml for the section shown above is as below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Salary, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
```

The fields in the images above are Age and Salary.  I am wondering how I can nicely fit the Validation message beside the field but not as 'clunky' - I tried adding @class="clearfix" to the ValidationMessageFor but it didnt seem to do what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to put it in a separate div:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        model => model.Surname,
        new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
</div>
```

Bootstrap should have a much easier time making this responsive.

Comment: doesnt boostrap work on 12 grid column - so in each of my rows I have 12 columns for laying out the fields as I need them - if I add an extra div with col-xs-5 this would bring the columns in the row to 17?

Comment: Good point, I updated my answer. The point is to put it in separate grids and let bootstrap do its thing.